# Create a file with 10 columns and 100 000 rows

Tags: java

```
private static final String SAMPLE_CSV_FILE_PATH = "./users.csv";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (
        Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(SAMPLE_CSV_FILE_PATH));
        CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT);
    ) {
        for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) {
            // Accessing Values by Column Index
            String name = csvRecord.get(0);
            String email = csvRecord.get(1);
            String phone = csvRecord.get(2);
            String country = csvRecord.get(3);

            System.out.println("Record No - " + csvRecord.getRecordNumber());
            System.out.println("---------------");
            System.out.println("Name : " + name);
            System.out.println("Email : " + email);
            System.out.println("Phone : " + phone);
            System.out.println("Country : " + country);
            System.out.println("---------------\n\n");
```

This is just the example of a few rows and columns. How to make a file with 10 columns and 100k rows and how to insert data by coding only?

Comment: What is a lakh row? Anyway, you an just nest another loop over the columns. `for(int c=1; c<= 10; c++) System.out.printf(“%-10s: %s%n”, “Column “+c, rs.getString(c);}` If you need actual column names you can either get them from a string array or read them out of the resultset metadata.

Comment: Lakh is an indian unit. Us western peeps don't understand it. Please use international standards.

Comment: @eckes Since you asked : A lakh is a unit in the Indian numbering system. `1 Million = 10 Lakhs` I agree OP should not have used it.

Comment: Oh just noticed, it’s not a result set but a CSV reader, so accessing the column name might be differently. But the for loop is the same (and as long as you use streaming while reading and writing the size of the file does not matter - however it’s unlikely anyone wants to read a table with million entries)

Comment: @eckes.. a file should contain 10 columns and 1 lakh(a hundred thousand) rows..the fifth column should be city & 10k records with 1 city like that 10 cities should be there in file.. and later by using nio package.. i need to split each city user in to separate file..

Comment: @eckes.. pls help me out with this.. u just give me some idea.. how to insert such a huge data by coding.. how to use loop in this... columns should be name..id..emailid..address.. city.. like remaining any 5 columns..

Comment: @farhanafatima I am not sure what you missing, your code looks fine in respect to large files. Do you get an error? - in that case the CSV reader you use would not be streaming)

Comment: @eckes.. No.. i am not getting any error..but i am confused... how to insert data in a file.. for example i need to give 10k rows with same city name.. here i can use loop.. but for remaining columns like name.. address.. etc.. i need to write code for all rows?....

Comment: @eckes.. i am confused.. totally.. you just suggest me how can i insert data for all 1 lakh rows.. pls

Comment: You need to be more specific, what do you want to do? Where do you want to insert which data in what Format?

Comment: @eckes...thanks for Ur quick replies....i need to a prepare a file with some details.. like employee details..or any customer details...it may be excel or csv file..and later i need to split this file in to separate files...give me code snippet for this... how to create a file with such details..

Answer (score 0):

public class FileGenerator {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    File file = new File("D:\\SampleFiles\\test.txt");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    String strName = "";
    String strDesi = "";
    String strCity = "";
    String strContac = "";
    fos.write("NAME\tDESIGNATION\tCITY\n".getBytes());
    for(int index=0;index<100000;index++){
        if(index < 10000){
            strName = "Farhana";
            strDesi = "Accountant";
            strCity = "Nagpur";
        }else if(index >= 10000 && index < 20000){
            strName = "Rahul";
            strDesi = "Manager";
            strCity = "Hyderabad";
        }
        else if(index >=20000 && index < 30000){
            strName = "Pavani";
            strDesi = "Architecture";
            strCity = "NewDelhi";

        }
        else if(index >= 30000 && index < 40000){
            strName = "Jay";
            strDesi = "Software Engineer";
            strCity = "Pune";

        }
        else if(index >= 40000 && index < 50000)
        {    
            strName = "Danish";
            strDesi = "Testing Engineer";
            strCity = "Mumbai";

        }
        else if(index >= 50000 && index < 60000){
            strName ="Lavani";
            strDesi = "Teacher";
            strCity = "London";
        }
        else if(index >=60000 && index < 70000){
            strName = "MoizAhmed";
            strDesi = "Customer service";
            strCity = "Newyork";
        }
        else if(index >=70000 && index < 80000){
            strName = "Azhar Khan";
            strDesi = "Front Manager";
            strCity = "Punjab";
        }
        else if(index >= 80000 && index < 90000){
            strName = "Rakesh kumar";
            strDesi = "Operation Analyst";
            strCity = "America";
        }
        else if(index >=90000 && index < 1000000){
            strName = "Zainab";
            strDesi = "Doctor";
            strCity = "Africa";

        }

        if(index == 99999){
            fos.write((strName + "\t" + strDesi + "\t" + strCity+ "\t" +strContac).getBytes());
            continue;
        }
        fos.write((strName + "\t" + strDesi + "\t" + strCity + "\t" +strContac+ "\n").getBytes());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

This is an example creating a pdf file :

```
Document document = new Document();
    try {
        document.open();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("iTextTable.pdf"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    PdfPTable tablepositions = new PdfPTable(10);
    addPositionsTableHeader(tablepositions);
    public static void addPositionsTableHeader(PdfPTable table) {
    Stream.of("Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3", "Column 4", "Column 5", "Column 6", "Column 7",
            "Column 8", "Column 9", "Column 10").forEach(columnTitle -> {
                PdfPCell header = new PdfPCell();
                header.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
                header.setBorderWidth(1);
                header.setPhrase(new Phrase(columnTitle));
                table.addCell(header);
            });
}
public static void FillPositionsColumns(PdfPTable table, String string, int n) {
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            table.addCell(string);
           }
}
FillPositionsColumns(tablepositions, "test", 10);
document.open();
document.add(tablepositions);
document.close();
```